# Eclipse 3.5.2 bug: save file not working

Tags: java, eclipse

I cannot save one of my edited files in Eclipse 3.5.2 (Build id: M20100211-1343, using Ubuntu 10.04 LTS). I really love when **the most important feature** of a program is not working.

Has anybody else experienced this bug? Should I report it at https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/? Or might it be caused by a plugIn?

In detail:

I edited a java file in the editor and cannot save it. Neither File -> Save nor Ctr-S is doing anything at all. When I switch to other files, I can save those. Looking under workspace, the file is still there, unmodified (same rights as other files, not saved recently).

Since this now happened for the third time, I checked at https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=%22save+file%22 but couldn't find anything appropriate. I checked several log files, e.g. workspace/.metadata/.log, but did not find a recent exception. Should I look in a different log file?

I did find several exceptions some time ago (>1 hour), see below. For my amateurish view, they don't seem to be the cause. Am I wrong?

- some by sonar plugin
- some by infinitest plugin
- one that sounds fitting, but the file not savable hasn't been moved and is under version control for quite a while. Bug 240286 and Bug 307140 don't seem to be my situation.

  !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.jdt.core 4 966 2011-08-31 16:01:08.633
  !MESSAGE Problems encountered while moving resources.
  !STACK 1
  org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceException: Problems encountered while moving resources.
      at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource.move(Resource.java:1476)
      at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.CopyResourceElementsOperation.processCompilationUnitResource(CopyResourceElementsOperation.java:331)
      at ...
  sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
      at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:559)
      at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:514)
      at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1311)
  Contains: Cannot move a file to a location that is not managed by SVN.  Try Team -> Copy followed by Delete.
  !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.core.resources 4 4 2011-08-31 16:01:08.633
  !MESSAGE Problems encountered while moving resources.
  !SUBENTRY 3 org.tigris.subversion.subclipse.core 4 -6 2011-08-31 16:01:08.633
  !MESSAGE Cannot move a file to a location that is not managed by SVN.  Try Team -> Copy followed by Delete.

Comment: Yes, I saw this bug several times when developing android application. It occurs  sometimes after running app. But it's happens too rare and random, so I can't reproduce it. I remember, I was curing it with 'close file' -> 'cancel'.

Comment: Yes, can't reproduce it either, but happens about every other month. Close file -> cancel sounds better then saving to a new file and afterwards copying. Thanks (+1). Oh, do you know whether it could be cause by a plugin like Subclipse, infinitest or sonar?

Comment: I use Subclipse a long time and never seen this bug. BTW why your Eclipse so old?

Comment: No, I don't have neither of these plugins, I had only `ADT` and `Scala IDE` plugins when the bug occurs.  Now I write most `scala` and `clojure` with `Scala IDE` and `countercloclwise` plugins and I didn't see this bug from those times. So I think it is somehow related to core java support in `eclipse`.

Comment: @4e6: Thanks a lot. So I know I don't have to be so skeptical about my plugins.

Comment: @umbr: Ubuntu 10.04 LTR's main repository only offers rather old Eclipse. And since I added a lot of plugins there a long time ago, I didn't want to go through all the hassle again for no reason. I'll probably wait for a good point in time to switch to Eclipse 4...

Comment: When I am unable to save files, I find that 'save all' works also.

Comment: It's 2017 and this is **still** an issue; I came here searching for answers. This is one of those exceptionally frustrating things like printers not printing. I never have this problem in Sublime Text...shouldn't an IDE be _better_ than a text editor at its specific task (actually letting you write code)?

Comment: I feel your pain, Hawkens. Did none of the two answers help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have also encountered the same problem with Juno. The answer is given in the post
[Why can't I save file in Eclipse Juno?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15414249/why-cant-i-save-file-in-eclipse-juno)

in Short, use save all (ctrl+shift+s) as a workaround till the problem is fixed in the IDE.

Thanks
Dheeraj

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: agree, will do so from next time on. Bytheway if you will take a close look, I gave the answer in short.

Answer (score 1):

For those who reached here by googling, I was facing similar issue. I use Eclipse Oxygen IDE for Java EE and I wanted to work on Scala so I installed Scala IDE and Scala Worksheet via help  > Install new Software

I created a Scala class file and typed some code but I was unable to save the file. Referring to suggestion in comment I did close > save. After this, issue vanished and I was able to save this file in usual way Ctrl + s

Answer (score 0):

I guess this error was really caused by Subclipse. If I remember correctly, I changed some settings in svn (mainly switching to the java protocol implementation) and the bug was gone.

Comment: I am not sure what exactly fixed the bug, though. I answer this question nonetheless because it has no answer yet and just gotten an upvote, so this bug still seems to occur for others.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by changing the setting as follow:
Window-> Preferences->PHP( as my issue was in PHP, if you are working on Java or other then you may need to select that one) -> Editor-> Save Action. I restore it to default.