# Why can't I save file in Eclipse Juno?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-juno

Sometimes I cannot save a file in Eclipse Juno.

The *File->Save* option is greyed out and *Ctrl+S* does not work. What's going on?

Comment: I experienced this as well, restarting eclipse did the trick.. Safe to say I will not be using Juno anymore!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is a known issue in Eclipse Juno:

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=396418

As a workaround, use 'Save All': *Shft+Ctrl+S*

Comment: FWIW, I just had a similar issue with Juno, wherein neither the "Save" and "Save All" buttons were greyed out, but clicking either did nothing.  The easiest workaround here was to copy the contents of the file's tab to another editor, close the tab, reopen it, paste the contents back in, and then save.

Answer (score 3):

Try: Save as. It will tell you what is a problem in your code. Probably you did "copy-paste" and some characters cannot be mapped using "US-ASCII" encoding characters.

Comment: Had the same issue, deleting the non-compliant chars allowed me to save

Answer (score 0):

You can also restart your Eclipse.
If you didn't use that "Save all"-workaround that was mentioned you will of course lose all your unsaved progress.
By restarting Eclipse you will be able to use the "normal" save again (until it is greyed out again...for me this happens like once per day)